# Double message display - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

In the following code, an error message is displayed when a value is entered incorrectly. Error message is displayed again when deleting the wrong value due to the field being empty. How can I stop the display of the message again?

```
Private Sub textbox1_Change()
   If TextBox1 < 1 Or TextBox1 > 31 Then
   Beep
   MsgBox "Please enter numbers between 1 and 31."
   TextBox1= ""
   TextBox1.SetFocus
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub textbox1_Change()
    Select Case True
        Case Len(TextBox1.Text) = 0

        Case TextBox1.Value < 1 Or TextBox1.Value > 31
            Beep
            MsgBox "Please enter numbers between 1 and 31."
            TextBox1 = ""
            TextBox1.SetFocus

    End Select
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub textbox1_Change()
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If TextBox1 < 1 Or TextBox1 > 31 Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "Please enter numbers between 1 and 31."
        TextBox1 = ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi _DisplayName_! Thank you for your answer. What is the reason for bringing `.text ` after `TextBox1`? Without `.text `, the code works.

Comment: Additional hints: 1) Successive `Me.Hide` and `Me.Show` statements before `TextBox1.SetFocus` actually sets the **Focus** as displaying the `MsgBox` window interrupts the communication. 2) Generally the `TextBox` control accepts only strings but converts comparisons with numbers (e.g. 1 to 31) internally preventing type mismatches here. 3) `.Text` assignments of textboxes automatically get assigned to their `.Value` properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub textbox1_Change()
   Static self_protect As Boolean

   If self_protect Then Exit Sub

   If TextBox1 < 1 Or TextBox1 > 31 Then
       Beep
       MsgBox "Please enter numbers between 1 and 31."

       self_protect = True
       TextBox1 = ""
       TextBox1.SetFocus
       self_protect = False
   End If
End Sub
```